# Ionic Binding Number to Button

Tags: css, html, typescript, button, ionic-framework

I'm looking for a way to bind numbers to buttons. For example, when you press 1 on a calculator, the number '1' is bound to it and displays on a monitor. Is there any way I can attach the number 1 to a button in Ionic?

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear, you didn't show what you did, what happens and what's expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention `typescript` so its `ionic-2` i guess,I suggest to use `angular` way of binding.

first declare variable in typescript file

**file.ts**

```
displayNum:any;
```

for displaying

**file.html**

```
<button ion-button>{{displayNum}}</button>
```